# Access Denied DHCP Tool

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, windows-server-2003-r2

I cannot figure out why this is happening, when opening the DHCP tool on my server, I get the following message.

> **Access Is Denied**
>   You do not have access to this DHCP server. To view information on a DHCP server, you must be logged in as an Administrator, DHCP Administrator, or DHCP User. 
>   
>   If you still cannot access the server, to retry the connection, either press <kbd>F5</kbd> or on the Action menu, click Refresh.

[image: DHCP Tool - Access Denied]

I've verified that I'm both a Domain Admin and a member of the DHCP Administrars group, and it does this regardless of what account is used to login. This works fine if I log into a different DHCP server on our network. It's only this server that it does not work on.

Some other relevant details:

- Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition
- Server Roles

  - File Server
  - Application Server (IIS)
  - Domain Controller (Active Directory)
  - DNS Server
  - DHCP Server
- Additional Software

  - Symantec Endpoint Protection (v12.1.1000.157 RU1)
  - Altiris (v7.1)

Comment: Are you login in as a user in the Domain Admins group. or the actual administrator account?  You might try using the actual administrator account to see if you get different results.

Comment: @Zoredache, Unfortunately, I don't know the password for the `Administrator` account itself. That is maintained by our Corporate IT. I've brought this issue up to them before, but they haven't done anything about it.

Comment: @druciferre so, is your account a member of the domain admins? Or the DHCP admin group in Active Directory?

Comment: @Rex, both Domain Admins and DHCP Administrators.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason this was happening. Someone changed the service to run as a domain service account. I changed it to run as the "Local System account" and now it works fine with no ill effects on DHCP function.